# Как сверстать крестик через border doshed?

Tags: html, css

Нужен такой крестик, вставлять картинкой не хочу, ибо нужно чтобы менялся цвет при наведении. Понимаю, что нужно делать через бордер, но не пойму как сделать пересекающиеся линии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.close{
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
.close:before,
.close:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
.close:before{
  left: calc(50% - 1px);  
  border-left: 2px dotted #00f;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.close:after{
  right: calc(50% - 1px); 
  border-right: 2px dotted #00f;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:hover:before,
.close:hover:after{
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="close"></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#" class="close">

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close:after {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

тест online: https://codepen.io/brissmyr/pen/egidw